# Como consigo acessar um atributo(que é uma lista) de uma classe por um método fora dessa classe em python?

Tags: python, classes, atributos

Tenho uma classe Loja que um dos atributos dela é uma lista (self.produtos = [ ]).

```
class Loja(Empresa):
    def __init__(self, nome, cnpj, razao_social):
        super().__init__(nome, cnpj)
        self._razao_social = razao_social
        self._funcionarios = []
        self._clientes = []
        self.produtos = []
```

Fora dessa classe tenho um método def relatorio que recebe como parâmetro um tipo de produto (eletrônico, alimentício etc) e percorre toda essa lista de produtos e imprime os nomes dos produtos.

```
def relatorio(tipo_produto):
    for i in Loja.produtos:
        if isinstance(tipo_produto, Produto):
            print(i)
```

O problema é que dessa forma que fiz não deu certo, o pycharm retorna um erro dizendo que "o tipo de objeto Loja não foi atribuído a Produtos". Se puderem ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: `self.produtos` não é um atributo da sua classe, é um atributo das *instâncias* que você criar a partir da classe. Você não pode acessar `Loja.produto` porque esse valor não existe no nível da classe, somente das instâncias criadas a partir dela. O correto seria inicializar uma instância de `Loja` com algo como `minha_loja = Loja(nome='Supermercado', ...)` e depois sim acessar o atributo `minha_loja.produtos`.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, se você definisse o método dentro da classe, o que me parece mais natural, bastava fazer:

```
self.produtos
```

Dentro da definição da classe, sempre que você quer chamar uma instância hipotética da classe você usa a key-word `self`.

No entanto, como está usando fora, creio que você cometeu um erro conceitual por não ter assimilado a diferença entre classe e instância.

A classe é uma "fábrica" de objetos de um determinado tipo, ela não é o objeto em si. Desse modo, se você quer usar um objeto da classe em uma função fora da classe, você precisa instanciar o objeto primeiro.

Segue um exemplo simplificado:

```
class Loja:
    def __init__(self, nome, cnpj, razao_social, produtos, funcionarios=50, clientes=50):
        self._razao_social = razao_social
        self._funcionarios = funcionarios
        self._clientes = clientes
        self.produtos = produtos

def relatorio(tipo_produto):
    for i in tipo_produto.produtos:
        print(i)

tipo_produto = Loja("Loja 1", cnpj=18299201, razao_social = "Nossa Firma", produtos = "anv bhs kok sijs".split(' '))

print(relatorio(tipo_produto))
```

Ouput:

```
anv
bhs
kok
sijs
```